# With mutation observer, Is there a way for me to get the id or class of an element or child that has changed?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what changes are made to the DOM and I'd like to know very specific information. I want to know which element was changed by id, class or if there is no id or class, I'd like to know where exactly I can find this element. I am trying to accomplish this with mutation observer. 
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v465D/26/) and here's the current code:

```
<div id="divTarget">
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<button id="btnUpdate">Update target</button>


var fnCallback = function (mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    alert(mutation.type, "added: " + mutation.addedNodes.length + "  nodes");
    alert(mutation.type, "removed: " + mutation.removedNodes.length + " nodes");
});
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(fnCallback),
    elTarget = document.querySelector("#divTarget"),
    objConfig = {
        childList: true,
        subtree : true,
        attributes: true, 
        characterData : true,
        attributeFilter : ['style', 'id'],
        attributeOldValue : true
    };

 observer.observe(elTarget, objConfig);







//below here is just the test code    
var btnUpdate = document.querySelector("#btnUpdate"),
fnHandler = function () {
    elTarget.innerHTML = "<h2>New content</h2>";
};

btnUpdate.addEventListener("click", fnHandler, false);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `mutation.addedNodes` and `mutation.removedNodes`?

Comment: Won't that only provide information for added or removed nodes? What if there's an attribute change to an element somewhere? like inline css or something.

Comment: Right, of course -- so you want `mutation.target`?

Comment: I think so, but I have been unsuccessful in obtaining the information. Target "Returns the node the mutation affected, depending on the type. For attributes, it is the element whose attribute changed. For characterData, it is the CharacterData node. For childList, it is the node whose children changed". So with target, I believe I may be able to obtain enough information to determine the specific element that was changed in some way. I have not been successful in accessing the contents of the record using target. mutation.target.childList for example, returns undefined.

Comment: DOM elements don't have an attribute named `childList`. Are you thinking of the `children` or `childNodes` attribute? In the case of a `childList` change, if you're interested in knowing what children of `target` were added or removed, look at `mutation.addedNodes` and `mutation.removedNodes`.

Comment: like mutation.target.textContent will give me the text within the element that has changed, but I've had trouble finding out a way to know for example, the id or class of the element that has changed or if the element has no id or class, a way to pinpoint exactly where that element that changed is, within the document

Comment: If you're interested in getting mutation information related to an attribute change on a child of an observed element, it might be easier just to make a new example of that case, rather than explaining it.

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v465D/28/ in this example, I have given elements nested within a div being observed, an id, a class and also have an element without either. Now, instead of using the update button, if you highlight the text of say the element with the id="hello", undefined is returned. If you press the update button, replacing the content of the div being observed entirely with text, the id of that div is returned with mutation.target.id. Is it impossible to know the id or class names of the elements nested within the observed div when they change?

Comment: Yes, `mutation.removedNodes` has all of the nodes that were removed by the mutation. For example, `mutation.removedNodes[1].id` is `hello`. (The whitespace also counts as nodes, so the `0` index is a text node; the `1` index has the first element.) Does that help answer your question, or do I still not fully understand your problem?

Comment: It definitely helps, thank you, I'm trying to instead figure out the nodes that were changed. I'm assuming removed means elements that were deleted. If so, I'm looking not for id's or classes of elements added or deleted but simply were changed somehow by either the content within them such as text or inline css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `mutation.target.parentNode` will give you the entire element. If you want to get just the id, you can get it from `mutation.target.parentNode.id`