# How to know, where exactly MutationRecord happened (multiple targets)?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, dom4

I trying to observe a group of elements. Quantity of elements can be various : from 1 to 10.

```
$observedElements = document.querySelectorAll('em.price'); 
// in that time length will be 3.

// $observedElements[0]  is a   '<em class='price'>10.15</em>'
// $observedElements[1]  is a   '<em class='price'>35.00</em>'
// $observedElements[2]  is a   '<em class='price'>48.95</em>'
```

So..

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(MutationRecord) {
    MutationRecord.forEach(function(MutationRecord) {
        if (MutationRecord.type == 'characterData')  {  
            console.log ('got it ... in elem. № ? ');   
            // which element is affected by this mutation? [0], [1] or [2] ?    
        };
    });
});

var observerConfig = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true, };

for (var i = 0; i < $observedElements.length; i++) {
    observer.observe($observedElements[i], observerConfig);
};
```

When value in some element became changed, an MutationRecord.type characterData is received.
In my example right now $observedElements[1]  changes from   '35.00' to     '25.00'

But how i can know that this changes was in emelent $observedElements[1]  ? 
In received target.textContent i gon only text value.

Comment: Why not simply use `target`? Or if you want to know the index simply assign `i` as a property of each element (e.g. `__index`) in your `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you explain a bit? I should add a property to observed elements? $observedElements[i] { 'element_id' : [i] }

Comment: A 'target' is a text node in my case ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text ). How i can use it to determine element where mutation was detected?

Comment: Found same question here, but he also not resolved - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078708/with-mutation-observer-is-there-a-way-for-me-to-get-the-id-or-class-of-an-eleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MutationRecord.target` already points to the item that changed, so you could find the root with

```
function findObserver(mutationRecord) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $observedElements.length; i++) {
    if ($observedElements[i].contains(mutationRecord.target)) {
      return $observedElements[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Works fine (for now). I mark this question as solved. Hope all will be fine in future tests :)

Comment: Is mutationRecord.target the target node before or after modification?

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky It is a reference to a DOM Node, which is the both the before and after because the node object itself isn't replaced, it is mutated.